# Retain column names after Boruta py: Python feature selection method

Tags: python, pandas

Below is Boruta implementation in python. It is a feature selection method which eliminates correlated, useless and redundant variables and helps to get only the relevant features from a dataset before performing ML algos or data analytics.

Basically if my df was like this:

```
 df
 Feature 1    Feature 2     Feature 3    Feature 4................Feature 700
```

Then after boruta I am getting an array:

```
 [True, False, True.....False] etc using feat_support
```

This  indicates that first and third feature are selected and second and 700th feature is not selected. But I am not getting column names, like feature 1, feature2 etc. as in original df

```
# NOTE BorutaPy accepts numpy arrays only, if X_train and y_train are pandas dataframes, then add .values attribute X_train.values in that case
X_train = X_train.values
y_train = y_train.values

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, class_weight='balanced', max_depth=5)

# define Boruta feature selection method
feat_selector = BorutaPy(rf, n_estimators='auto', verbose=2, random_state=1)

# find all relevant features 
feat_selector.fit(X_train, y_train)

# check selected features 
[IN]feat_selector.support_
[OUT]
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
           False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
           False, False, False,
           .................. False, False, False, False, True])
```

More code:

```
  [IN]print (feat_selector.n_features_)
  [OUT]441 #441 features were selected out of total 700 in my case.

  # call transform() on X to filter it down to selected features
   [IN]X_filtered = feat_selector.transform(X_train)
   [OUT]
[[ 0  0  0 ...  0  0  0]
 [24  6  0 ...  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 ... 43  0  0]
 ...
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0  0]]
```

So basically I am getting list of features selected in `feat_selector.support_`; but I am not getting the column names as in original X_train via Boruta. How to retain column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code, `support_` is a mask array.

```
support_ : array of shape [n_features]
        The mask of selected features - only confirmed ones are True.
```

So you can use this on your columns names to get the feature names.

```
X_train.columns[feat_selector.support_]
```

to get the column names that have been selected.